# how to enable mass payment from PayPal account

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal

I am getting  error while transfer send money to another `PayPal` account using mass pay

> "We're sorry, but your PayPal account isn't currently eligible to send
>   mass payments. Please contact either PayPal Customer Service or your
>   account manager."

I had call with `PayPal` customer care and he said mass pay is already activated in you account.

Is there any missing setting in my `PayPal` account? Do i need to enable "Payout" from PayPal setting ?

Answer (score 1):

For those that had their Paypal Rep confirmed it was enabled but still have the issue, it's a bug in their system. Here is my Rep's response:

> Here is a workaround until they fix this issue:  They can either paste the following URL into their address bar, https://www.paypal.com/payoutsweb/batchFileUpload, or they can go to “Tools, All Tools, Mass Payment” and it will work from there.  It is not working when you go to “Tools, Send Money, Make a Mass Payment” but there is a ticket open on this currently.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error, Mass Payment is not enabled on the account. Perhaps the Customer Service representative looked up a different account.

To be sure, try sending a MassPay via API and check what error is thrown.

Here is a Sandbox example with my Sandbox credentials; feel free to use my account to test. Change the credentials to yours and remove **.sandbox** from the URL to test live.

```
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?USER=pro22_1222868134_biz_api1.paypal.com&PWD=XPBWBJ9AFZ9X748L&SIGNATURE=ABhqmE8JdSxFSHp2C6TGP6yXBWsJANNpoeLALseoabPIe162v-muDlb0&VERSION=109.0&METHOD=MassPay&RECEIVERTYPE=EmailAddress&CURRENCYCODE=USD&L_AMT0=0.01&L_EMAIL0=buyer@lore.org
```

Mass Payment enabling requires a vetting process and unfortunately many small businesses are not eligible.